# file_get_contents проверка наличия пустоты

Tags: php

Есть код который выводит список друзей, которые приходят в url в формате json.

```
$GetFriendList = file_get_contents($url);
$FriendList = (array) json_decode($GetFriendList) -> friendslist;
```

Когда список открыт он возвращает массив друзей в json

```
"friends": [
            {
                "steamid": "76561198005279071",
                "relationship": "friend",
                "friend_since": 1389891560
            },
            {
                "steamid": "76561198008622881",
                "relationship": "friend",
                "friend_since": 1503832130
            },
            {
                "steamid": "76561198017105821",
                "relationship": "friend",
                "friend_since": 1416392358
            }]
```

А если список друзей закрыт то он возвращает пустое значение

```
{

}
```

Так сделать чтобы он пропускал этот запрос если он возвращает пустое значение, и продолжал дальше выполнять запросы другие?

Comment: `if(empty($FriendList))`

Comment: нет, конечно. вы же его строите сами. Потом посмотрите, когда построили, если пуст, занимайтесь другими делами.